# Why null pointer exception on junit testing on android - but no error when stepping in debugger?

Tags: android, junit

Trying to understand why it works fine when I do a Debug As... Android/Junit Test.
Stepping though with the debugger, works fine. Run As, throws the NP exception.
Yes, I did do a Project/Clean and build.

I am trying to use the hierarchical-state-machine utility class in android [StateMachine.java](http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/util/StateMachine.java) [see http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/util/StateMachine.java] 
When trying to run junit tests in the emulator on Eclipse/Win7, I get a NullPointerException

```
   LogRec lr = aa.hsm.getLogRec(0);
   assertNotNull(aa.hsm.aState);
   assertNotNull(lr.getState());
   assertEquals(aa.hsm.aState, lr.getState()); <------NullPointerException
```

I am mystified that the two asserts above it to test for nulls, do not throw an error.
Stepping though with the debugger, works fine. Run As Android Junit Test, throws the NP exception.

An example of how junit is used to test HSMs is in http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/tests/coretests/src/com/android/internal/util/StateMachineTest.java line 1815 onwards.

Comment: well, you are calling getState() twice. no idea what this particular method is doing, but consider that `deleteFile('foo.txt')` would work only the first time it's called. the second time you call it, the file's already gone and the delete fails.

Comment: @MarcB An example of how junit is used to test HSMs is in http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/tests/coretests/src/com/android/internal/util/StateMachineTest.java line 1815 onwards.